# Make a reusable function that changes slightly depending on where I use it

Tags: c++, c++23

Basically, I have a function that I will use in two places in my code, which have an `if` condition that varies depending on where I use it. In one of these places the `if` condition is like this:

```
void foo(/* parameters */) {
    //...
    if (age >= 18 && alcohol_consumed < 0.2) {
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

and in the other is like this:

```
void foo(/* parameters */) {
    //...
    if (height_m >= 1.82 && is_rich == true) {
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

Is there a method to write that function only one time and change the `if` condition accordingly, or do I need to declare separate functions? I want to achieve re-usability of this function with less changes in my code.

I have tried to make a macro to change the condition:

```
#define foo_condition(x) \
#if x
    age >= 18 && alcohol_consumed < 0.2 \
#else
    height_m >= 1.82 && is_rich == true \
#endif
```

but I just have read that it is not possible to make an `#if` in a macro definition, so I don't really know how to do it.

Comment: Certainly there's a way to do so. It's called "templates". Do you know what C++ templates are, how they work, and how to use them?

Comment: Yes, but how? what I know is that a template function can have various implementations. What I want is to have only one implementation (write the function ones) but be able to make that distinction(like with parameters or something like that).

Comment: That's exactly right: the template parameter will control the discriminating behavior. And combined with `if constexpr`, the sky's the limit. Looks like you figured it out by yourself...

Comment: oh wow, I had see the if constexpr statement but I had never use it, so is something strange to me. You just open my mind right now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use a template, or since C++20, use an auto function parameter:

```
void foo(const auto& cond) {
    ...
    if (cond) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

If `A` and `B` are either a `bool` or something that evaluates to a `bool` you don't even need a template and can just use:

```
void foo(bool cond) {
    ...
    if (cond) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Should `const auto&`  just be `bool`?

Comment: @康桓瑋 It can be.  both will give the same thing.  I went with this to make it more generic in case they actually need to use `A` or `B` more

Comment: Maybe I don't explain myself. A and B are conditions, not values. I don't want to write the same function twice, so I want to be able to write it once but can put a different condition depending on where I call it.

Comment: @Mr.Barbo I get that.  You put the condition in as the function parameter.  like `foo(str != nold || tokens_bool[idold])`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you need add argument to `foo`.

Explicit template way:

```cpp
tempalte <typename F>
void foo(F f) {
    ...
    if (f(arg1, arg2, arg3)) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}

void usage()
{
    foo([idold](auto a, auto b, auto c) { return a != b || c[idold]; });
}
```

Or using `std::function`

```cpp
void foo(std::function<bool(const std::string&, const std::string&, std::array<int, 3>&)> f) {
    ...
    if (f(arg1, arg2, arg3)) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}

void usage()
{
    foo([idold](auto a, auto b, auto c) { return a != b || c[idold]; });
}
```

Note I'm blindly filling gaps form your question. Simply there is no enough details in your question to make this answer better.